Is it possible to train Neural networks for time series forecasting using elastic distances (such as dtw) as a loss function?
Normally, elastic distances are used as ways to tell how similar two time series are. Examples of these are dynamic time warping and move-split-merge and many more. And I read some researches such as this, that used them for classification and clustering purposes. They generally perform great for those scenarios. But I couldn't find much about using them for forecasting purposes.
I want to build a NN with a direct strategy that can forecast 10 values at a time. The big idea is for the loss function to be an elastic distance so it tells the NN how similar the predictions are to the actual. But I found it hard to implement. Has anyone tried to build a neural network with an elastic distance as a loss function?
PS: I also understand that normally gradient boosted models (like lightgbm) perform very well for forecasting purposes. This is for the sake of experimenting.

My answer is certainly not covering all aspects of your question, but here are some thoughts about it.
i) DTW is not differentiable as is, due to the MIN operator.
ii) you could have a look as softDTW which is differentiable
iii) I have share some code about a new kind of neural network, that I have entitled "time elastic neural network", based on KDTW, a time elastic matching kernel similar to softDTW. here is the teNN code.
